# Why can't someone edit more than five of his/her own posts per day?

Tags: discussion, edits, rate-limiting

I was improving some of my old posts on Stack Overflow when I ended up encountering this:

> You have already edited 5 of your own post today; futher edits are not
>   allowed until tomorrow

I know this it is not a major deal, but what's the logic underneath to this restriction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's to prevent rage-quits.

There have been multiple cases of people rage-quitting by deleting or vandalizing their own posts.

So the simple solution is to rate-limit it. Anyone who deletes or edits 5 of their own old posts in a single day will be blocked and then automatically flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: Well thought out, was not imagining such scenario.

Comment: The lesson being: If you rage-quit, vandalize *other* people's posts. No limits there.

Comment: @lunboks haha nice commented, couldn't hold the laugh :D.

Comment: Well, I believe that most people are not so cruel. As well, I'm sure that if necessary, the tech team could revert all your actions in a given period of time if there was a reason to do so.

Comment: @tohecz: you're almost certainly right, but those rate-limits are not here to stop "most people". They are here to stop the very small fraction of people that *will do* nasty stuff when they rage-quit.