# Vandalism by OP

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged those question

- [Getting “AWT EVENTQueue-0” java .lang.nullpointerexception error [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499902/getting-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-error)
- [How to add Jpanel to Jframe from different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481855/how-to-add-jpanel-to-jframe-from-different-classes)
- [Creating an actionlistener from a method in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510383/creating-an-actionlistener-from-a-method-in-another-class)
- [awt eventqueue 0 nullpointerexception error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536790/awt-eventqueue-0-nullpointerexception-error)
- [awt eventqueue 0 nullpointerexception (sample code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537190/awt-eventqueue-0-nullpointerexception-sample-code)

by two different users IDs [@user2188332](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2188332/user2188332) and [@john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797299/jonn), where both OPs edited valid question to [E.T call home](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083866/) (copy only from one thread)

> sgahpzjob\oiepsnhg\sgjv; lzfrnhb;zds/ \;fkm;akf;skma\vkmesokg[\pa[
>   bldzajhblzdjmnlopiaerjgpidejo ewligj ej WJwj\ o\'PEUWe'ge AAPO p'w
>   jW'[agh' awe gtg g g g g arehgae hae |Vl ]o \T HSRH S TSHT S H

my questions

1. can OPs again to edit your posts, after `This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends in 7 days.` expired
2. can be those two account merged
3. couldn't be better to delete a.m. threads, originally I want to flag these questions as non_answer, then flag for delete question, but in due in all respect with answerers I flagged as vandalism only

Comment: Vandalism like this is [capped at 5/day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165885/why-cant-someone-edit-more-than-five-of-his-her-own-posts-per-day) to limit the damage.

Comment: Looks like they're [oscillating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166098/200500).

Comment: @Asad nice, another one in the oscillation club! ;) For the record this case is different, it's frustrated user who most likely got question banned and decided to rage quit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any time you ever see a post that is vandalized you can flag it and let a mod deal with the post.  In some cases, if it doesn't appear to be malicious or widespread, you might roll it back once, but if it is ever applied a second time you should always flag rather than getting in an edit war.

The mod will be able to determine what the final state of the post should be, they can lock the post if they feel that it's needed to prevent further editing, and they can take any further actions they deem necessary against the user for vandalizing the post.