# Answers being blocked from deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, rate-limiting

Sorry if this is perhaps a *duplicate* of an already answered question. I am very curious of the purpose of being blocked from deleting answers after the limit of 5 daily deletions have been reached?

Comment: This is probably [to prevent rage-quitting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165885/why-cant-someone-edit-more-than-five-of-his-her-own-posts-per-day/).

Comment: I believe it is mostly to prevent people from rage-quitting/vandalizing their posts by deleting too many too quickly.  I guess the question for you is why do you want to delete more than 5 in a day?

Comment: There is no need to really delete old answered questions, I guess for the fact that some people like to clean up answers that are old and not rated.

Comment: @hwnd "not rated" <> "useless and should be deleted."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ragequits and other forms of abuse.

We've had more than a few people get upset about something and decide to start just deleting everything they've ever written. This can be *incredibly* disruptive, not to mention tedious to repair.

If you hit the limit, a mod-flag is raised as well - they'll look at your activity and see if it's a symptom of a larger problem.

If you're just cleaning up old answers that don't add anything useful to the other answers on the same questions, don't worry about it.

Comment: Care to explain `symptom of a larger problem`? And yes I was mainly referring to just cleaning up answers that are really not useful compared to other answers.

Comment: I mean that most folks don't start deleting a bunch of well-regarded answers for no reason. If they're involved in a dispute with someone else on the site (just for instance), that's something that'll need some attention.

Comment: Ok I can see how that would affect some people, and the fact of reputation.

Comment: Beyond that, this sort of "taking my ball and going home" attitude *hurts The Internet* - useful information is now gone, links are broken, questions are unanswered. This is one reason why everything posted here is CC-Wiki licensed: no one, not us, not the author, gets to unilaterally "take back" something that has enriched the programming community.