# Any chance for reconsideration of the 5 deletes/day limit?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

I know this [has been asked already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85523/you-have-already-deleted-5-of-your-own-posts-today-further-deletes-are-blocked), but that ended with

> I'll see about what we can do about possibly lightening the load
>   without harming its intent

And the limit is still in place.

My situation is exactly like that of the author of the original question - I sometimes clean up old, useless, answers of mine (which are either bad, duplicates of other answers, or just generally useless in hindsight), and hitting this limit after finally getting the motivation to do clean-up is a bummer :-)

So, could this limit please be reconsidered? I don't mind if after 5 deletes I had to re-login, do a captcha, do an email-verification round, etc., if you still feel the need to protect against abuse.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165885/why-cant-someone-edit-more-than-five-of-his-her-own-posts-per-day

Comment: and here's another - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129634/reconcile-the-5-edits-limit-with-a-large-set-of-updates-of-ones-old-answers . its just that none of them are too recent

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that answer you pointed to has an unclear "every day" bit that seems to indicate the limit has more to do with activity than rep, and if this indeed exists there's nothing about it that i could find in official docs

Comment: There are no docs, on purpose. There is a limit, there is a good reason for the limit, but the limit does scale with your reputation.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: That's for edits - it's not clear if the same applies to deletions. I know I've seen users with very high 5-digit rep counts being stuck at 5 deletions per day, but there has been one instance of a 20k user being flagged after editing 40 of their meager 500+ answers.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: ah, yes, deletion vs. editing. Ahem, that is a difference indeed.

Comment: Right, so a similar limit for *editing* has been adjusted to scale with reputation. I am a little skeptical about the need to *delete* more than 5 posts a day though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that just depends on how often youre motivated to do the cleanup. in my case, not very often :-)