# Improve the rate-limit to prevent rage-quits via self-edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, rate-limiting

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4005019/eric?tab=activity) has been editing all of their posts to `askwale` and similar stuff for a while now. It's gotten to about 30 edits, but they're not being blocked from editing their own posts because this wouldn't trip [the 5-post self-edit rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165885/why-cant-someone-edit-more-than-five-of-his-her-own-posts-per-day) because they're only editing 3 posts of theirs.

It would be amazing if the system could detect mass-edits which delete most of the content in the post, and automatically ratelimit these users. This would prevent a ton of rollbacks.

Comment: Feature suggestion would be automatic lock (content-dispute) on post with auto-flag for moderator attention. Bonus point for auto-rollback to the version prior to edit that started the war.

Comment: The mentioned user no longer has an account. For reference, one of his 3 posts was edited at least 40 times b.c of him removing all the content and rollbacks by other users. His other 2 posts had about 15-25 edits.

Comment: How frequent a problem is this really? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits must have further reduced it, no?